# debugging VGA signal timings for 640x480 @ 60hz

Tags: frame-buffer, video

I am trying to get started with implementing a basic display (i.e a simple red screen) onto a VGA monitor by programming a Xilinx spartan3a fpga for the same.
I have studied about the signal timings for a 640x480 @ 60hz display and implemented the same,however it turns out, The monitor does not recognize it.I tried using a sample test file (it was a bit file so couldn't reverse engineer it), and it worked perfectly so i think there's no issue with the hardware.

```
module main(
    clk,
    Hsync,
    Vsync,
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    led
);

//inputs:
input clk;
//outputs:
output Hsync;
output Vsync;
output[2:0] Red;
output[2:0] Green;
output [1:0] Blue;
output [7:0] led;
//wire
wire[9:0] hcounter;
wire[9:0] vcounter;
wire PixClk;
wire locked;
//regs:
reg reset;

clkgen inst(
.CLKIN_IN(clk), 
.RST_IN(1'b0), 
.CLKIN_IBUFG_OUT(), 
.CLK0_OUT(PixClk), 
.LOCKED_OUT(locked)
);

VGAcontroller controller1(
    .locked(locked),
    .pixel_clk(PixClk),
    .hsync(Hsync),
    .vsync(Vsync),
    .hcounter(hcounter),
    .vcounter(vcounter)
);

generateRGB RedScreen(
    .RedPix(Red),
    .GreenPix(Green),
    .BluePix(Blue),
    .Hcount(hcounter),
    .Vcount(hcounter)
);

assign led[0]=locked;
assign led[7:1]=7'b0;
endmodule
```

the clockgen module generates a 25mhz signal, and led[0] goes "ON" when the dcm-pll has a locked onto the frequency.(works in the implementation).

'VGAcontroller' module is responsible for the 'Hsync' and 'Vsync' signal generation taking in 'Pixelclk' and locked as inputs with the rest as outputs. The 'generateRGB' module takes in the 'Hcounter' and 'Vcounter' values to provide the necessary analog values via 3 registers.

VGAcontroller.v

```
//800 horizontal counts
//525 vertical counts

module VGAcontroller(
    locked,
    pixel_clk,
    hsync,
    vsync,
    hcounter,
    vcounter
);

input locked;
input pixel_clk;
output hsync;
output vsync;
output[9:0] hcounter;
output[9:0] vcounter;

reg hsync;
reg vsync;
reg[9:0] hcounter;
reg[9:0] vcounter;

always @(posedge pixel_clk or posedge locked)
begin
    if(locked)
    begin
        hcounter=hcounter+1'b1;
        case(hcounter)
            10'b0:              hsync=1'b1; //d<0>
            10'b1010010000: hsync=1'b0; //d<656>
            10'b1011110000: hsync=1'b1; //d<752>
            10'b1100100000:                 //d<800>
            begin
                hcounter=10'b0;
                vcounter=vcounter+1'b1;
            end
        endcase
        case(vcounter)
            10'b0:      vsync=1'b1;                 //d<0>
            10'b0111101010: vsync=1'b0;         //d<490>    
            10'b0111101100: vsync=1'b1;         //d<492>
            10'b1000001101: vcounter=10'b0; //d<525>
        endcase
    end else begin
        hcounter=10'b0;
        vcounter=10'b0;
    end
end
endmodule
```

the timing sequence is as follows : [visible range]->[front porch]->[Sync pulse]->[back porch]

the reason for starting the counter with visible range is that the values of counters correspond to the location of the pixel on the screen.
As of now , the 'generateRGB' simply assigns the register responsible for the red color to have full voltage while green and blue to be 0 i.e to print a red screen.

P.S. I am not exactly sure whether this question is valid for this forum or whether tags do good justice but if there is a better one, kindly recommend.thank you!

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope or logic analyzer you can use to capture the signal and see if it looks right?

Comment: @DanHulme luckily I got access to a CRO, I had a look at the outputs from the sample bit-stream and my code, turns out the hardware did not generate any signal from my code, which is not what the test bench showed. I tested out the signal individually by assigning it to a switch and toggling manually, that worked, so the ucf constraints were ok. Beyond that I have no clue as to where the issue resides.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have an FPGA problem, not a graphics problem. [electronics.se] might be more help to you.